# windows server AppFabric installation error

Tags: error, installation

i have 2 windows server 2008 r2 on vmware.
one of them is Domain
the other one is joined to domain that it's name is "win sharepoint"
i am trying to install sharepoint 2013 on "win sharepoint"
i installed all prerequisites except windows server appfabric
when i trying to install sharepoint , it started to downloading windows server appfabric but after that it shows:
windows server APPfabric     installation error
[image]

after restarting it shows this passage
what shoud i do?
 i'm using iso file of sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

You could download the AppFabric installer manually (but don't run it) http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235496 
, and then run the installer through the Prerequisites installer like this: prerequisiteinstaller /appFabric: WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.msi.

There is more info at this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/12/26/install-and-download-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-offline-manually.aspx

In my experience, if the AppFabric service isn't installed 100% correctly, you will have all kinds of sporadic SharePoint problems (crashes) in the future.  I also suspect (but have never confirmed) that trying to run the prerequisites installer multiple times sometimes gets the machine into a state where the App Fabric service can never be installed, so you might consider re-installing the OS if this keeps happening.

I've also found that the AppFabric service installation has problems if the machine (and the user account you are installing under) are not correctly joined to the AD domain.  You might check the clock on your VM to make sure its within a few minutes of the clocks on your domain controllers, and also make sure that your new VM is only using Domain Controllers as its DNS servers (so it can look up all those SRV records, which other DNS servers may not have).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Remove the “PSModulePath” entry in system environment variables and then try to run the “Install Software Prerequisites“. Now everything runs fine.

Solution 2: Run the prerequisites in the command prompt and try to install the required files.

Hope You Find This Useful.